# Rendering Swedish Å Ä and Ö with groff, mupdf

Tags: mupdf, groff

I am learning to use groff as an alternative to Latex and am struggling with rendering Å Ä and Ö
characters.

In an English only setting, I have been running groff with:
`$ groff -ms example.ms -T pdf > example.pdf`
and then viewing my pdf with :
`$ mupdf example.pdf`

I see in the man pages groff_tmac(5) that there is support for Swedish and when I try to extrapolate the example from French in the man pages to Swedish I do not achieve the results I want. I am still getting two strange characters in place of every Å, Ä, or Ö.

I am trying the command
`$ groff -ms -msv example.ms -T pdf > example.pdf`

I have scoured the web both in Swedish and English (Swedish results even worse...seems like no one is using Groff) and am finding zero examples.
I don't need the answer, just where someone smarter than myself would start looking. People in my circle just suggest Latex but I am determined to use the much lighter Groff.

I am expecting to have Å Ä and Ö print nicely, so I can do my assignments in groff instead of Latex.

Thank You!

Comment: You need support for UTF8, not Swedish or French. In UTF8 non-US_ASCII characters are converted to two or more bytes. Try `-Tutf8` or `-Tpdf`

Comment: As for `seems like no one is using Groff`... no one is using LaTex outside universities either.

Comment: Running command; '$ groff -ms example.ms -Tutf8 -Tpdf > spec.pdf' Gives me the same result I had before. If I run only with -Tutf8 then when trying to view with mupdf I get an error. If I forego the pdf and just run it straight to the terminal I get the same unchanged content as if I hadn't added -Tutf8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I have accented or non-standard-ascii characters in my input text, I run the inputfile through `preconv`, which solves almost all my problems.

```
preconv inputfile | groff > outputfile
```

If you dislike typing the separate `preconv`, you can also run `groff` with `-k`.

If I use the following inputfile:

```
test
.br
I am expecting to have Å Ä and Ö print nicely,
```

and run it through `preconv`, I get

```
.lf 1 inputfile

test
.br
I am expecting to have \[u00C5] \[u00C4] and \[u00D6] print nicely,
```

Of course, you can put in the `\[u00C4]` etc. by hand, but that makes `groff` a lot less lightweight. And the output of `groff` then becomes:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I personally would edit my compiler command to replace with `sed` the characters I need. I tried preconv but wasn't working for me. Also, sometimes preconv messes up characters at the beginning of a line and it's just not reliable. So, I would use this command to compile my documents:

Note: See list of characters and their unicode code with `man groff_char`, you'll find Aring, Adieresis and other chars.

```
sed "s/Å/\\\[u0041_030A\]/g;s/Ä/\\\[u0041_0308\]/g;s/Ö/\\\[u004F_0308\]/g;" file.ms | groff -ms -T pdf
```

Prettier (just add more sed lines with as many characters with the unicode code found in in `man groff_char` you want to replace):

```
sed "
s/Å/\\\[u0041_030A\]/g;
s/Ä/\\\[u0041_0308\]/g;
s/Ö/\\\[u004F_0308\]/g;
" file.ms | groff -ms -T pdf
```